# PrimeFaces get row data fetching previous data

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Below table is a form of question and answer. At the first time table will show the question and if user click on reset button then a drop down box will appear. And user can reset the question. Now problem is that when I click on reset and changed the question and click on save button, bean class didn't get the updated question. It print the previous question. Below is my code::

```
 <p:dataTable id="alphaTable" var="cs" binding="#{challengeSetBean.alphaChallengeSetTable}"
                        value="#{challengeSetBean.challengeSet}">
        <p:column id="col" style="width:20px;font-size:12px;padding-left:7px;padding-bottom:7px;padding-top:7px;">
                    <p:panel columns="1" style="border:0px;">   

                              <h:outputText value="#{cs.question}" id="question" rendered="#{!cs.editMode}"/>
                              <p:selectOneMenu value="#{cs.id}" rendered="#{cs.editMode}" id="questionDropDown">
                                 <f:selectItems value="#{challengeSetBean.availableQuestions}"  />
                              </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:inputText value="#{cs.question}" id="customQuestion" rendered="#{cs.editMode} &amp;&amp; #{cs.custom}"  style="width:300px;"/>
                            <p:inputText value="#{cs.answer}" id="answer" rendered="#{cs.editMode}"/>
                    </p:panel>          
                </p:column>

                <p:column  style="width:28px;font-size:9px;padding-left:7px;padding-bottom:7px;padding-top:7px;">

                        <p:commandButton value="#{msg.updateAccount_reset}"  action="#{challengeSetBean.editAnswer('alpha')}" immediate="true" rendered="#{!cs.editMode}" update="alphaTable" >

                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton value="#{msg.common_save}" action="#{challengeSetBean.saveAnswers('alpha')}" rendered="#{cs.editMode}"  immediate="true" update="alphaTable"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="#{msg.cancel}" action="#{challengeSetBean.cancelAnswer('alpha')}" rendered="#{cs.editMode}" ajax="true" immediate="true" update="alphaTable"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="#{msg.common_delete}" action="#{challengeSetBean.deleteAnswer('alpha')}" rendered="#{!cs.editMode}"  immediate="true" update="alphaTable"/>

            </p:column>  

            </p:dataTable>
```

Bean:

```
      QuestionAnswer selected = (QuestionAnswer) challengeSetTable.getRowData();
       System.out.println(""+selected.getQuestion());
```

Comment: instead of binding, don't you better use row selection p:ajax event? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf

Comment: If I use selection instead of binding, getting a null pointer exception in getRowData().

Comment: of course you will have to change your current code, I just thought it will be better achieved by using built in event of the table and without binding